# Child element is not moved on page when parent's sibling is hidden, in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a jQuery-enabled web page with image links to external sites, for use as a browser home page.  Each set of related links (development, social, etc) is contained in a folder, which can be expanded or collapsed by clicking its header.  This works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

[image: Screenshot of working web page]

In Internet Explorer (surprise!) I get this weird behaviour.  Suppose there are three vertically stacked folders.  If I collapse the first folder, the second and third folders and their contents are shifted up to fill the space, *except* the contents of the second folder, which remain in the same absolute position on the page.

I've created a cut-down version of the page, with the bare minimum required to exhibit the problem.  Here, I have folders called "Red", "Green" and "Blue", each containing a single image.

[image: Screenshot of example page]

If I click the red header, the blue image is shifted up with its folder, but the green image remains in the same position, now behind the blue image.

[image: Screenshot of example page after clicking the read folder header]

However, if I set the border-style on the folder header and body elements to "none" instead of "solid", the green image is shifted with the other elements as expected.

Web page folder.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='folder.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'></link>
    <title>Folder Example</title>
  </head>
</html>
```

Style sheet style.css:

```
div.folder-header
{
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
  border-color:#e0e0e0;
  border-width:1px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

div.folder-body
{
  background-color:#f8f8f8;
  border-color:#e0e0e0;
  border-width:1px;
}

div.link-viewport
{
  position:relative;
}

img.link-image
{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  border:none;
}
```

JavaScript file layout.js:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var border = true;

    var folder = function(title, src)
    {
        var section = $('<div>').appendTo('body');
        var header = $('<div>').addClass('folder-header').text(title).appendTo(section);
        var folder = $('<div>').addClass('folder-body').appendTo(section);
        var viewport = $('<div>').addClass('link-viewport').css('width', 64).css('height', 64).appendTo(folder);
        var image = $('<img>').addClass('link-image').attr('src', src).appendTo(viewport);

        header.css('border-style', border ? 'solid' : 'none');
        folder.css('border-style', border ? 'solid' : 'none');

        header.click(function()
        {
            folder.toggle();
        });
    };

    folder("Red", "red.png");
    folder("Green", "green.png");
    folder("Blue", "blue.png");
});
```

Image files red.png, green.png and blue.png:

[image: Image file 1]

[image: Image file 2]

[image: Image file 3]

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: sorry, man. I created a jsfiddle of it (http://jsfiddle.net/EhPk8/23/) and ran under IE8 and couldn't get it to fail...

Comment: This is pretty speculative, but I'd consider trying to actually serve it instead of just opening a local file and see what happens. I've had IE be pretty flaky on me before when it comes to accessing local resources.

Comment: Jonathan, that's really weird; your jsfiddle works for me (in IE9) as well, but my test page still fails.  There aren't any major differences between the jsfiddle and the files I uploaded, so possibly jsfiddle is doing something that exercises Internet Explorer differently.  I'll have to compare the HTML elements by eye. )-:

Comment: Bubbles, thanks for the suggestion, but I'm hosting the complete page (as in the first screenshot) from a local Tomcat server, and that has the problem.  I did try hosting the test page from there too, but it still fails.

Comment: does the lack of 'body' play any role? Maybe jsfiddle's injecting that automatically. Perhaps create a container div in markup and then append to that?

Comment: Possibly OP means that it fails in IE7; I see the problem described when trying it in IE9, IE7 mode.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the suggestion, but adding an explicit `<body>` and container element didn't make any difference.  Looks like what jsfiddle is supplying is the `<!DOCTYPE>`, as that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accordion seems to work in IE8+, but I was able to see the problem in IE9 using IE7 mode (press F12 to open IE dev tools -> browser mode = "IE7", document mode = "IE7 standards").  I got it working by making these changes:

**CSS**: Add `overflow: hidden;` to the ruleset on `div.folder-body`.

**JS**: Remove `folder.toggle();` at line 18 and insert

```
if (folder.height()) { 
    folder.hide(); 
    folder.height(0); }
else { 
    folder.show(); 
    folder.height(64); 
}
```

I don't understand why, though!

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EhPk8/25/

Comment: The problem was actually that I had failed to add a `<!DOCTYPE>` statement to my HTML file, so Internet Explorer was running in quirks mode, equivalent to IE5.5.  Thanks for putting me on the right track!  Btw, I get other layout issues if I run it in IE7 mode, but I've decided not to worry about that; I seriously doubt any of my users will be running such an old version, and I'll upgrade them if they are. (-:

Comment: I should also mention that the `folder.toggle()` replacement didn't work for me; when I tried it, `folder.height()` always returned 64, even when the folder was already hidden.